# Character left on the input stream causing infinite loop

Tags: c++, input, while-loop, infinite-loop, cin

I'm new into programming and today I'm here because I need help with a program that I'm writing. This program is an exercise from the book : Programming principles and practice using C++. I have to write a program that uses a function to find the min, max, mean and median element in a `vector` of doubles. I tried to wrote this loop but I'm having some problems with reading numbers. Here is the loop :

```
void reading_loop()
{
cout << "Enter a series of numbers ending with any non-digit character : "; 

while (true) try {

    vector<double> values; 
    double x; 
    while (cin >> x) values.push_back(x);

    Stats result = get_stats(values); // a stats holds the results
    print_vector(values); 
    print_stats(result); 

    cout << "Try again : "; 

}
catch (runtime_error& e) {
    cerr << "Error : " << e.what() << '\n'; 

}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "Oops, something went wrong somewhere \n"; 
}
```

}

The object called result of type `Stats` is a simple struct that the author told me to use to hold the results from `get_stats(values)`. Basically the problem with this program is in the `while(cin >> x)` loop, when I execute the program and I enter the first series of numbers and stop reading using the character :  ' ; ' the program prints the corrects results as it should, but then It skips reading with `while(cin >> x)` bringing the program into an infinite loop. I read about question like this on the forum but I am new to programming so I don't know of functions such as `cin.ignore()` or `cin.clear()`. How would you solve this problem ?

Comment: *"...so I don't know of functions such as `cin.ignore()` or `cin.clear()`"*.... well that is how you solve the problem

Comment: @CoryKramer So how would you solve this problem using those functions ?